# Anomaly on CSS code, varying positions regarding browser/resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm using this same CSS code on a website since months. And it works perfectly, keeping image and text positions regardless of browser and screen resolution.

I have now just moved this same identical code into another site, and it looks it's giving issues with CSS since both browsers and screen res is moving img and text in different positions.

May you please report me the error I may have typed in the code? Thx.

```
.up { display: block; position: relative; margin: auto; }

.left { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 75%; left: 0; }

.right { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 75%; left:71.35%; }

.down { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 2223%; left: 0; }

.middle { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 830%; left: 1.5%; }

.logo { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 30%; left: 21.5%; }

.folder { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 120%; left: 3%; }

.title { display: block; font: 1.3rem/1.0 Verdana; position: absolute; top: 340%; left: 23.6%; }

.text { display: block; font: 1.05rem/1.2 Arial; color: white; position: absolute; top: 1010%; left: 2.3%; }

.moretext { display: block; font: 0.95rem/1.1 Tahoma; position: absolute; top: 1280%; left: 2.75%; }

.signup { display: block; font: 1.2rem/0.7 Arial Black; color: red; position: absolute; top: 720%; left: 32%; }

.object1 { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 305px; left: 32px; }

.object2 { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 305px; left: 171px; }

.object3 { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 305px; left: 309px; }

.object4 { display: inline-block; position:absolute; top: 305px; left: 448px; }
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work on every screen resolution as their aspect ratios would all be different, are you sure there wasn't something in the original code that was maintaining an aspect ratio based on the width or height

Comment: It would help if you could add the html code or even better a full example with a github code snippet (has a button above the question editor) or a plunker showing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding this stuff:

## outline { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }

## wrapper { float: left; background: #fff; width: 600px; margin: 0 !important; margin: -15px 0 0 0; /* IE hack */ padding: 0; }

## content { float: left; width: 600px; height: 439px; }